# Field Reference check

Tags: metadata-api

I am trying to find a function in Metadata API that can give you list of references for a selected field.
I am confident such a function exists somewhere, because if you try to delete a field, Salesforce attempts a "try delete" that gives you errors with list of all the components where the field is referenced. Can someone guide me where to find this method?

Answer (score 4):

Despite your confidence, there's actually no way to get at this information directly. While it is true that there is a metadata table that is consulted to make sure that a deletion won't break your code, that's not exposed to developers. About the best that you could do is set up a destructiveChanges.xml file and deploy with with the [checkOnly](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_deploy.htm#deploy_options) flag set to true. If the call succeeds, then there are no remaining references. Otherwise, you'll get a list of errors that correspond to the references stored in the metadata. You'll want to consider voting on [Where is this field used (page layout or formula)](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Br56AAC), which has been merged with many other related ideas about how to identify field references in some way (by API, report, or a "Where is this field used?" button).